# How-To Mock WCF Services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

How-to Mock WCF Services Proxies with Rhino Mocks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your service so that it implements an interface.  Then you can either mock the interface in your client or create a fake implementation of the interface to use in your tests.

Comment: I would say that is more of an integration test than a unit test and I wouldn't use mocking.  Create a "fake" service with a different endpoint and test against that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but it something that I have recently done. In my scenario I have some Acceptance Tests which talk to a Wcf Service but I didn't want to use the real service. I did actually do a [blog post](http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2011/09/hosting-mock-as-wcf-service.html) on it but here is the low down.

A static class for creating a wcf service for a given object:

```
public static class MockServiceHostFactory
{
    public static ServiceHost GenerateMockServiceHost<TMock>(TMock mock, Uri baseAddress, string endpointAddress)
    {
        var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(mock, new[] { baseAddress });

        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>().InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TMock), new BasicHttpBinding(), endpointAddress);

        return serviceHost;
    }
}
```

Creating a mock and using it as a wcf service:

```
Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add<ServiceContractAttribute>();

var myWcfServiceMock = Substitute.For<IMyWcfService>();
var mockServiceHost = MockServiceHostFactory.GenerateMockServiceHost(myWcfServiceMock , new Uri("http://localhost:8001"), "MyService");
mockServiceHost.Open();
...
mockServiceHost.Close();
```